# Como atualizar partes do site sem recarregar javascript

Tags: javascript

Bom a minha dúvida é a seguinte, a minha página recebe informações do banco de dados, como por exemplo a temperatura. Eu queria saber como faço, para que se eu alterasse no meu banco de dados a remperatura, a minha página também alterasse sem ter que tar a atualizar a página (refresh ou F5).

Ou seja, se eu alterar uma pequena parte do texto do site, o site não precisa de atualizar para que possa aparecer a nova temperatura.

Comment: O outro tópico nada tem a haver com a minha pergunta.

Comment: O outro tópico menciona a utilização de AJAX, que pode utilizar para obter o resultado que deseja no seu site.

Comment: Depois de ler a sua pergunta, o que me veio a mente é: "AJAX", tal como o colega @lazyFox disse. Concordo que é uma pergunta totalmente diferente, mas veja a resposta do Sergio que está lá.

Comment: Dê uma olhada em [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events).. Quando alterar a temperatura no Banco de Dados o server avisa os clientes que foi alterado... Aí é só  alterar o site por javascript.

Comment: Com toda a certeza esta pergunta já foi feita várias vezes, e a resposta mais simples é "AJAX". No entanto, acredito que a pergunta que foi marcada como duplicata não explica bem o problema desta. Lá são mostradas formas de modificar o comportamento de um link para utilizar o AJAX, o que não é o problema desta pergunta.

Comment: Mostre um pouco do seu código Gonçalo